# Invertible function that "messes" order

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, inverse, inverse-function

I am looking for an invertible discrete function $f$ such that given some integer n, if i apply $f(i)$ for $i=0,\dots,n$ I would get all the integers in range $[0..n)$ exactly once, but in a "messy" - "random" if you will manner.

I thought about finding a generator for the group $(\Bbb Z_n,\cdot)$, but im not sure if it would work for any given $n\dots$ (would it?)

any other ideas?

Comment: I guess the word you're looking for is [*messy*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/messy)?

Comment: @Rahul yes, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are talking about is defining $f(i) := x^i$ for $i>0$ and $f(0) = 0$ where $x$ is a generator of the multiplicative group of integers mod $n$ -- called a *primitive root*. To avoid the predictability of the $f(0)$, you could define $f(0) = a$ and $f(i) = x^i + a$ (mod $n$).This is a good idea, as usually it will give that random-seeming arrangement, but it requires the group in question be cyclic, which is only true if $n =$ 1, 2, 4, $p^k$, or $2p^k$ for prime $p$.

Comment: How about defining f as a composite of such functions for a composition of n=n_1+...+n_k such that each n_i have the suggested property?

Comment: @OfekRon Yes, that's possible - because Quinn's method enumerates not only the multiplicative group, but also $0$. Hence by combining this method for co-prime prime powers and using the Chinese Ramainder Theorem, you can achieve your goal for arbitrary $n$ (as long as it is not divisible by $8$). Note that it is not necessary to do the CRT computation in *every* step as most of the time we still just multiply by a constant modulo $n$. beware of $i$ that are multiples of a prime power dividing $n$, though.

Comment: That's a good suggestion!

Comment: Just thought about my comment again, something tells me it will not work, i have a feeling that some integer may output twice or more

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen can you convert your comment to a solution? like explicit definition of f(i) that would satisfy the needs?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen whats so special about integers that divisible by 8?

Comment: @OfekRon There is no primitive root modulo $8$. Then again, one can use almost *any* sequence modulo a possible $2^k$ factor of $n$. If at least one other prime power gets "messed up" then the CRT will typically hide any regularity of other prime powers.

Comment: Well im trying to generate a solution from your comments, but im getting too confused, is it possible to create such function for any n?

Answer (score 2):

In order to extend *Quinn*'s answer to more general $n$:

Suppose you can write $n=ab$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and you have a "nice" random permutation function $f_a$ modulo $a$, but not modulo $b$. Then we can simple pick a "bad" random permutation function  $f_b(i)=i\bmod b$ and combine those to 
$$f_n(i)=j\bmod n$$
where
$$j\equiv f_a(i\bmod a)\pmod a\quad\text{ and }\quad  j\equiv f_b(i\bmod b)\pmod b $$
Of course we'd *expect* things to be "even messier" if $f_b$ is also a nice random permutation. In the light of Quinn's answer, we should be in good shape as long as $n$ is not a power of $2$. (Though the permutation the above method produces in extreme cases such as $3\cdot 2^k$) might not be very random).

Some specific method for powers of $2$ should be used. I suggest multiplication $\bmod 2^k$ with an odd factor $u\approx \phi2^k$ where $\phi$ is the golden ratio.